# Open last file in dir with vim

Tags: bash, vim

I write a journal and name the files in a YYYY-MM-DD.markdown fashion. When I want to amend something to the last entry, I would like to open it with a shortcut, instead of writing out the full date (bash completion does not help at all).

How can I open the last file (in alphabetical order) in vim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's really the last file:

```
vim $(find . -type f  -maxdepth 1 | sort | tail -n 1)
```

Or to be more specific about markdown files:

```
vim $(find . -name "*.markdown" -maxdepth 1 | sort | tail -n 1)
```

You can of course create an alias for that in your bash profile.

```
alias newest='vim $(find . -name "*.markdown" -maxdepth 1 | sort | tail -n 1)'
```

<sub>Edited because xargs and vim causes some serious trouble after exiting it. Have to find out why this is. I also had backticks before, but using `$()` instead of backticks is the new way to go.</sub>

Comment: sounds good. But happens if I have the following filename: "2011-05-19.markdown; rm -rf ~"? Isn't xargs insecure?

Comment: Who would have such a file name? :) If you want to call it that way, `xargs` is of course insecure. But: Turns out you can't use `xargs` and `vim` together anyway. See my edited post above, this should be easier.

Comment: As I have learned on #bash, you should not ask "Who has these filenames?" but make your code secure so that it can handle it.

Comment: @queueoverflow Fair enough, I was just kidding :) Thanks for the edit!

Comment: `find` doesn't return sorted output, so the `tail -n 1` will return the last item in the output of find which isn't necessarily the newest file. Adding a `| sort` after `find` should address this.

Comment: Awesome for finding the last logged exception in my project, thanks !
Note: I changed the order to `-maxdepth 1 -type f` to get rid of that `find` command warning

Answer (score 1):

```
vim "$(ls -1 *.markdown | tail -n 1)"
```

Works with spaces in filenames, and does need neither `find` (which recurses by default, which might not be what you want) nor `sort` (output of `ls` is alphabetical by default).